# How to solve this memory errors in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I've got a package that elaborates XML documents. The package runs shedulated daily but after a few weeks, now every day it gives errors like:

```
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 4032 bytes (qmxdGetDocElem,qmemNextBuf:alloc)
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 1032 bytes (qmxlu subheap,qmemNextBuf:alloc)
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 40 bytes (kxs-heap-f,frame segment)
```

and I've never met such errors.
If I try to perform manually the package in other moments it works and terminates reguraly.
Can someone give me some suggestion? What about this type of errors? I work on Oracle 10g

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: How are you processing the XML?  Post code!  If you are using DBMS_XMLGEN, don't forget to call `DBMS_XMLGEN.CLOSECONTEXT`.

Comment: The DBA has added more memory but the error keeps on
In my package I use many times the native function

DBMS_XMLDOM.newDOMDocument

but I never use the

DBMS_XMLDOM.freeDocument

Could that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes.  That could be ONE of your problems.  Try dumping contents of `v$temporary_lobs` for your `SID` at the beginning and end of one iteration of your process.  There should not be anything left over that you weren't expecting from your code.  If there are, add the call to `freeDocument`, repeat the test, and see if that gets them all.

Comment: I've solved the problem by inserting the statement DBMS_XMLDOM.freeDocument

Comment: Great!  I added an answer so that, if you accept it, this question won't show up as open/unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DBMS_XMLDOM` to create documents.  This allocates memory that must be freed after you are finished accessing the document.  You can free the memory by calling `DBMS_XMLDOM.freeDocument` at the end.